# Updating a ServiceWorker only for new clients

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to make the update of my ServiceWorker work.

I have an old service worker, some windows are under it's control. Now there is a new version of the ServiceWorker. It get installed properly. But it does not get activated for new pages. My aim is to keep the old one for old pages and the new for every new tab/pages viewed.

Any idea how to accomplish this ?

Edit:

Is how I check that the the new service worker is not updated:

I have a sendMessage method:

```
sendMessage(message): Promise {
    const channel = new MessageChannel();
    const p1 = channel.port1;
    const result = new Promise(resolve => {
      p1.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        resolve(data);
      };
    });
    serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(message, [channel.port2]);
    return result;
  }
```

Then I use it to check on page start

```
this.ready = this.sendMessage('version')
  .then(version => {
    if (version !== process.env.BUILD_NUMBER) {
      console.log('$$ Version mismatch, reinstalling service worker');
      throw new Error('build mismatch');
    }

    return serviceWorker.controller;
   });
```

And I answer in the ServiceWorker

```
self.addEventListener('message', ({ data, ports  }) => {
  const client = ports[0];
  if (data === 'version') {
    client.postMessage(process.env.BUILD_NUMBER);
  }
});
```

Edit

Adding:

```
event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
```

helps but it activate the ServiceWorker also for old clients.

Thanks

Comment: *"But it does not get activated for new pages.*": let's consult our crystal balls to find out why; or in other words: you should provide some concrete information/code for us to see why your new service is not activated for new pages.

Comment: I added information on how I check that the versions mismatch. I tried forcing update() and reloading the page when the version mismatch but I end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`self.skipWaiting()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting) within a service worker's `install` event handler will cause the newly installed service worker to immediately activate, even if there's an existing, older service worker that's currently active for other clients. Without `self.skipWaiting()`, the newly installed service worker will remain in a `waiting` state until all other clients of the previous service worker have been closed.

Calling [`self.clients.claim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) from inside the `activate` event handler is sometimes used as well, but only if you want the newly activated service worker to take control of already-open clients that are either uncontrolled, or controlled by an older version of the service worker. In your case, it sounds like you **do not** want that behavior, so you shouldn't call `self.clients.claim()`.

Comment: From testing (on localhost in Chrome) it seems like `skipWaiting()` itself will cause *the newly activated service worker to take control of already-open clients that are either uncontrolled, or controlled by an older version of the service worker*?